# undefined symbol: spotrs_ in torch7

Tags: ubuntu, lua, torch

I am having problem with torch7 in Ubuntu 14.04. Error:

error loading module "libtorch" from "libtorch.so": undefined symbol: spotrs_

I am trying to import it in lua 5.1.5. I don't have any problem in Mac.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Torch [ezinstall](https://github.com/torch/ezinstall) installer? `spotrs` is a LAPACK function, so you need to make sure you have e.g [OpenBLAS](https://github.com/torch/ezinstall/blob/83d8ccb/install-deps#L7-L22) properly installed.